# How to pass a readable object stream into a Handlebars template

Tags: node.js, templates, stream, handlebars.js

For example, I am using npm's [accountdown module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accountdown) which has a `list()` method to list all accounts. `list()` returns a readable object stream, so my current solution is to create a list from that stream and pass it into my template.

Is there a way for Handlebars to read a stream directly, and avoid having to read the stream into memory as a list, so it can be read from my Handlebars template?

Here is an example of my situation:

Here I am constructing a list `results` from my account list stream `stream` so I can pass it to my template `account-list-template`:

```
var results = [];
var stream = server.accounts.list();

stream
  .on('data', function (data) {
    results.push(data);
  })
  .on('error', function (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    var ctx = {accounts: results};
    return response().html(server.render('account-list-template', ctx)).pipe(res);
  });
```

I tried using the [handlebars-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-stream) module, but I could not pipe my list object stream to my template. I was only able to pipe my template to the object, shown here:

```
return server.accounts.list().pipe(handlebars(server.render('account-list-template'))).pipe(res); // produces x times the template
```

but the results are incorrect in that the entire template is rendered for each account in the stream, rendering x pages for x number of accounts.

Here is my template:

```
{{#extend "layout"}}

{{#replace "body"}}
<div class="container">
    <hr>
    <div class="sheet-list">
        <h1>Master account list:</h1>
        {{#each accounts}}
        <div class="list-item clearfix">
            <a href="/account/edit/{{ key }}">
                <div class="list-item-info">
                    {{ key }}
                    {{ value.email }}
                    <h3 class="list-item-name">{{ key }}</h3>
                    <div class="list-item-description">{{ value.email }}</div>

                </div>

                <div class="list-item-actions">
                    <form action="/account/delete/{{ key }}" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" class="destroy-sheet">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> destroy
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        {{/each }}
    </div>

</div>

{{/replace}}

{{/extend}}
```

Comment: Had the same question. Currently checking this out: http://handpipe.github.io/